# Retrieve back a variable property

Tags: powershell

I'm developing a script for PS and I have a list of languages in a ComboBox. When I select some of them to be shown + I format them like that `$language.DisplayName` (`$language.Name`; `$language.ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName`) and I set it to a variable. That way, when I display the list, I see something like: `English (en; eng)`. What I want is to retrieve just the `.Name` property back, so I can do things with it (the script is about multimedia files).

```
$texto_seleccionar_vo = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label -Property @{
    Text = "some text here"
    AutoSize = $false
    TextAlign = "MiddleLeft"
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,20)
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,85)
}

##### I call every country and language available. I select those I want. Right now I'm using the LCID property, which is unintelligible for humans and the property `.Name` would be better, but that's not a matter right now.

$paises = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures(
    [System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) |
    Where-Object {
    $_.LCID -eq "9" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1033" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "2057" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "6153" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "3081" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "10" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "3082" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "22538" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "11274" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "2058" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "9226" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "8202" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "16394" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "13322" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "23562" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "10250" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "14346" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "15370" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "12" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1036" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "3084" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "17" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "7" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1031" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "3079" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "16" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "18" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "8" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "29" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "21" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "6" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "41" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "15" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "57" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "25" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "37" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "22" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "2070" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1046" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "30724" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "11" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "31" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "14" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "31770" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "86" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "3" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "45" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "19" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "2067" -or
    $_.LCID -eq "1043"
} 

##### I format it, I want to display a combination of many properties.

$paises_bcp47 = foreach ($idioma in $paises){
$idioma.DisplayName + " (" + $idioma.Name + "; " + $idioma.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName + ")"
}

##### Undetermined language doesn't exist in CultureTypes but it does for ISO. I have to create it myself and I set the same properties I need from the rest of languages to interact with it as if it was just another language.

$idioma_indeterminado = [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = "Indeterminado"
    Name = "und"
    TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "und"
    ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "und"
}

##### Even if there is just one undetermined language, I do a foreach to set the same format as the rest of languages, so it will be displayed like any other language of the list/combobox.

$indeterminado_bcp47 = foreach ($indeterminado in $idioma_indeterminado){
    $indeterminado.DisplayName + " (" + $indeterminado.Name + ")"
}

##### I do exactly the same for the "no linguistic content" language.

$idioma_ningun_contenido_linguistico = [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = "Ningún contenido lingüístico; No aplicable"
    Name = "zxx"
    TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "zxx"
    ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "zxx"
}

$ningun_contenido_linguistico_bcp47 = foreach ($zxx in $idioma_ningun_contenido_linguistico){
    $zxx.DisplayName + " (" + $zxx.Name + ")"
}

##### I group every language so I can sort them alphabetically

$paises_bcp47 = $paises_bcp47 + $indeterminado_bcp47 + $ningun_contenido_linguistico_bcp47 | Sort-Object

$caja_seleccionar_vo = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox -Property @{
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,85)
}

##### I show every language on the list

$caja_seleccionar_vo.Items.AddRange($paises_bcp47)

##### I set the 34th as the default one.

$caja_seleccionar_vo.SelectedIndex = $caja_seleccionar_vo.Items.IndexOf($paises_bcp47[34])
```

After that, I want to set the selected language to the variable `$idioma_vo`. But I don't want the `English (en; eng)` output. I need the "en", which would be the `.Name` property.

I've tried things like

```
$idioma_vo = $caja_seleccionar_vo.SelectedIndex.Name
```

Or things like that, but nothing. Obviously. `$idioma_vo = $caja_seleccionar_vo.SelectedIndex` returns 34 and my goal is that it should return "en" (or whatever language is selected).

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I've finally done it thanks to your help!

```
$idiomas_seleccionados_lcid = @(
    9, 1033, 2057, 6153, 3081, 10, 3082, 22538, 11274, 2058, 9226, 8202, 16394, 13322, 23562, 
    10250, 14346, 15370, 12, 1036, 3084, 17, 7, 1031, 3079, 16, 18, 8, 29, 21, 6, 41, 15, 57, 
    25, 37, 1, 22, 2070, 1046, 30724, 11, 31, 14, 31770, 86, 3, 45, 19, 2067, 1043
)

$idiomas = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures(
    [System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) |
    Where-Object {$idiomas_seleccionados_lcid -contains $_.LCID} | 
    ForEach-Object {
         # output an object with properties 'Text' and 'Value'
         # the 'Text' is what the combobox displays, the 'Value' is the language Name property you want to retrieve
         [PsCustomObject]@{
             Text = '{0} ({1}; {2})' -f $_.DisplayName, $_.Name, $_.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
             Value = $_.Name 
         }
    }

$idioma_indeterminado = [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = "Indeterminado"
    Name = "und"
    TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "und"
    ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "und"
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
         [PsCustomObject]@{
             Text = '{0} ({1})' -f $_.DisplayName, $_.Name
             Value = $_.Name 
         }
    }

$idioma_ningun_contenido_linguistico = [pscustomobject]@{
    DisplayName = "Ningún contenido lingüístico; No aplicable"
    Name = "zxx"
    TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "zxx"
    ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "zxx"
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
         [PsCustomObject]@{
             Text = '{0} ({1})' -f $_.DisplayName, $_.Name
             Value = $_.Name 
         }
    }

$idiomas = $idiomas + $idioma_indeterminado + $idioma_ningun_contenido_linguistico | Sort-Object -Property Text

$caja_seleccionar_vo = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox -Property @{
    Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,85)
    DisplayMember = "Text"
    ValueMember = "Value"
}

[void]$caja_seleccionar_vo.Items.AddRange($idiomas)


$caja_seleccionar_vo.SelectedIndex = $caja_seleccionar_vo.Items.IndexOf($idiomas[34])
```

I had to add undetermined and the zxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text and value for each combobox item to different things.
To do that, create the `$paises` array as an array of **objects** like this:

```
$lanCodes = 9, 1033, 2057, 6153, 3081, 10, 3082, 22538, 11274, 2058, 9226, 8202, 16394, 13322, 23562, 
            10250, 14346, 15370, 12, 1036, 3084, 17, 7, 1031, 3079, 16, 18, 8, 29, 21, 6, 41, 15, 57, 
            25, 37, 1, 22, 2070, 1046, 30724, 11, 31, 14, 31770, 86, 3, 45, 19, 2067, 1043

# get an array of objects to use in the combobox
$paises =  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) |
           Where-Object { $lanCodes -contains $_.LCID } | 
           ForEach-Object {
                # output an object with properties 'Text' and 'Value'
                # the 'Text' is what the combobox displays, the 'Value' is the language Name property you want to retrieve
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    Text = '{0} ({1}; {2})' -f $_.DisplayName, $_.Name, $_.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
                    Value = $_.Name 
                }
           } | Sort-Object -Property Text
```

Next the below demo form code should show you how to use that:

```
# demo form

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select Language'
$form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 440, 300
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.TopMost = $true
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'

$combo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.Anchor = "Left","Top","Right"
$combo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 100, 100
$combo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 275, 21
$combo.DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
$combo.AutoCompleteSource = "ListItems"
$combo.AutoCompleteMode = "Suggest"
# determine what the 'Text' and 'Value' properties for the items are
$combo.DisplayMember = "Text"
$combo.ValueMember   = "Value"

# now add the $paises objects to the combobox
[void]$combo.Items.AddRange($paises)

# set the selected item
$combo.SelectedIndex = 34
$form.Controls.Add($combo)

# create OK and Cancel buttons
$btnOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOK.Name = "btnOK"
$btnOK.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 100, 200
$btnOK.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 120, 31
$btnOK.Text = "OK"
$btnOK.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.Controls.Add($btnOK)

$btnCancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel"
$btnCancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 260, 200
$btnCancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 120, 31
$btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.Controls.Add($btnCancel)

$form.AcceptButton = $btnOK
$form.CancelButton = $btnCancel

$result = $null
$answer = $form.ShowDialog()
if ($answer -eq 'OK') { 
    $result = $combo.SelectedItem.Value
}
$form.Dispose()
```

If something has been chosen in the above dialog, the `$result` should give you the Name property only like `ru`